# PostgreSQL's magic with low free space on system drive

Tags: performance, macos, postgresql

I have the PostgreSQL server running on my Mac OS X 10.7.2. Sometimes the random query, especially the

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW <Name> AS SELECT * FROM <Table>;
```

failed with code `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR = 7` and message

```
ERROR:  invalid page header in block 4169 of relation "pg_type"
```

After 2-5 attempts the query is finished OK with no errors.

I think the problem caused by the low free space on the system drive because the application works fine without database errors on mac with a lot of free space on system drive.

How could I specify the error causes the query failed?

**UPDATE: Added a logs**

```
sh-3.2# cat postgres_LOG.1324986905
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2011-12-27 15:54:32 MSK
LOG:  checkpoint record is at 1/EEE1161C
LOG:  redo record is at 1/EEE1161C; undo record is at 0/0; shutdown TRUE
LOG:  next transaction ID: 1814900; next OID: 808694
LOG:  next MultiXactId: 1; next MultiXactOffset: 0
LOG:  database system is ready
LOG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 1073763426, limited by database "my_db"
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49159
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49161
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49162
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49263
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49264
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
ERROR:  invalid page header in block 4169 of relation "pg_type"
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49266
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
ERROR:  invalid page header in block 4169 of relation "pg_type"
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49273
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49274
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49276
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49277
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49362
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=49363
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=50293
LOG:  connection authorized: user=my_db database=my_db
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: Don't the logs give any further information?

Comment: Did you check the file system of the affected data directory? Any errors there?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like disk/filesystem corruption. I'd suggest you do a dump/reload cycle on the database as soon as you can - as well as a filesystem and disk hardware check if possible.

Shouldn't be related to the free disk space - that would give you a different error.

Answer (score 0):

More likely some system tables are damaged. At least `pg_type`. And since `pg_type` is usually quite small (a dozen pages/blocks) but your number (4169) is quite large, there might be other problems lurking like to few vacuuming.

Comment: The OP is clearly creating temporary views frequently - that causes an increase in the size of some system tables, such as pg_type, so it may not be strange at all.

Comment: @MagnusHagander: IMHO even frequent use of temporary tables or views should not blow up system tables _that much_ when otherwise proper vacuuming takes place.

Comment: Depends on the amount of concurrent activity happening and the complexity of it - vacuum might not get to it soon enough. But either way, that's likely unrelated to the problem - the file is clearly that big (or the error message should be a different one)